# Asus EZ Flash sees my usb but does not see bios update file

Tags: boot, usb, bios, updates, asus-laptop

I am trying to update BIOS on my ASUS transformer book T100TAM laptop on Version 300. After entering EZ flash, it recognizes my USB but not bios update file. I tried to download and use different bios file (dedicated to differrent OS), and EZ flash recognizes it but of course shows error about incompatible file. I am using windows 8 32 bit OS. Do you know where can be the problem?

Comment: Typically updaters that are *for* an OS are meant to be run with that OS, not EZ Flash. There are specific files to be used directly with the EZ Flash.

Comment: I tried to run update file which is compatible with my OS and it did not work

Comment: EZ Flash is independent of the installed OS and doesn't need one. That was my previous point. If you downloaded the Windows executable version that is to be run from Windows. EZ Flash runs entirely in UEFI and expects something like a .bin, rom or something like, not Windows exe.

Comment: If you are running Windows 8, why are you attempting to update the firmware, outside of Windows and the executable ASUS provides for that purpose?

Comment: There is no option to download .exe file from official asus website, there is only .300 file to choose (https://www.asus.com/2-in-1-PCs/ASUS_Transformer_Book_T100TAM/HelpDesk_Download/) that is why I am trying to upgrade bios though EZ Flash.

Comment: The most recent BIOS file ASUS has posted on the T100TAM support page links instead to a file for a different model, the T100TA**N**. This can be confirmed by inspecting the file name and also by attempting to load the file in the WinFlash utility, which states very clearly that the BIOS file is not suitable for the current model. This is why EZFlash refuses to allow the file to be selected - it is not a valid BIOS file for the T100TAM. ASUS goofed and posted the wrong file. As far as I can tell, the most recent BIOS available for the T100TAM is version 400 posted on 2016-05-19.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Version 300 BIOS Firmware for ASUS Transformer Book T100TAM

[image: ASUS firmware]

from the website https://www.asus.com/2-in-1-PCs/ASUS_Transformer_Book_T100TAM/HelpDesk_BIOS/

[Here is the instruction how to update the firmware using EZFlash](https://www.asus.com/sg/support/FAQ/1008859/).

1. Extract the content of the downloaded zip file into a USB device
2. Boot to BIOS, select `Advanced`, `Start Easy Flash`
3. Browser to the file you downloaded and proceed to flash the BIOS

[image: EZFlash]